# A given curve is an helix?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

Given the vectorial function $$\vec{r}(t)=\cos(t)\,\mathbf{i}+\sin(t)\,\mathbf{j}+\ln (\cos(t))\,\mathbf{k},\quad 0\leq t\leq \pi/4$$
How can I justify that a curve is an helix? How do I express it mathematically? Does it have anything to do with the curvature? I calculated the length $s(t)$ of the curve $C$ as a function of $t$. I also expressed the curve $C$ as a function of the arc length $s$ and calculated the intrinsic trihedron $(\vec{u}_T(s), \vec{u}_N(s), \vec{u}_B(s))$ as a function of $s$. And finally I found the curvature $\kappa (s)$ as a function of $s$.

Comment: Try to show your work or your thoughts about the question. This will help others in giving answers appropriate to your skill and experience. Also, giving some context about the problem would help others tailor their response to your needs. Overall, this would increase your chances of getting a proper answer.

Comment: At mathematics stackexchange, we expect questions to give proper context and show due effort. As it stands, your question is unlikely to be well-received by the community and will probably be downvoted and closed.

Comment: For more information see the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help&grqid=03N9NNbV&s=1&hl=en). You may also find [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/homework-reasonable-to-have-no-clue) useful.

Comment: For example, you may want to ask yourself- What is a helix? What does its equation look like? Can I relate that with the given equation?

Comment: It has the property that the tangent line at any point makes a constant angle with a fixed line called the axis. But how can I express this mathematically for solve my problem! An helix is a curve $x=a\cos t$, $y=a\sin t$, $z=bt$, but my $z$ is really different.

Comment: NB: There's also the rule that the points of the helix must be at a constant distance from the axis. For your curve $r$, can you determine what the axis would have to be, assuming that $r$ *is* a helix?

Comment: @JohnHughes I can't think of anything right now.

Comment: What's the tangent line to your curve? What ways do you have to represent an axis, whatever the axis happens to be? A constant angle means a constant sine, cosine, tangent, etc.

Comment: Can you find 3 points of your curve? Can you find a line equidistant from these three points? Hint: it's the $z$-axis.

Comment: Careful here!! What I usually call a *generalized helix* is characterized by the property that the tangent line makes constant angle with a fixed line (sometimes called an axis). This is totally different from a circular helix (although a circular helix is a special case) ! The OP mentioned this generalized definition and usual the circular one in the same comment. Better check definitions!